# JavaScript execute event each every time

Tags: javascript, time, delay

I have this:

```
let time = store.time;
const run = setInterval(() => {
    const delay = store.delay;
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Execute event....");
    }, delay * 1000);
    time--;
    if (time === 0) {
        clearInterval(run);
    }
}, 1000);
```

I just want to run a process indicating a time and delaying the time at the same time, for example:

time=10 ; delay=2, then the process will be executed when the time is equal to: 2, 4, 6, 8 and 10

time=10 ; delay=3, then the process will be executed when the time is equal to: 3, 6 and 9

time=10 ; delay=4, then the process will be executed when the time is equal to: 4 and 8

time=10 ; delay=5, then the process will be executed when the time is equal to: 5 and 10

It's not currently working that way, it's only running 10 times, why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [a promise and `async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises#async_and_await) you can use a normal for loop to log the steps at the right intervals.

```js
// Return a promise that resolves after a
// certain duration
function delay(step) {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => res(), step * 1000);
  });
}

// Accepts a limit, and a step count
async function loop(limit, step) {

  // Log the first step and then...
  console.log(step);

  // ...loop over the rest of the numbers calling
  // the delay function on each iteration
  for (let i = step + step; i <= limit; i += step) {
    await delay(step);
    console.log(i);
  }
}

const limit = 10;
const step = 2;

loop(limit, step);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use both `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()`. Use `setInterval()`, with the interval being the delay converted to milliseconds. At each repetition, subtract the delay from the total number of times, and when this reaches the end, stop the timer.

```js
let time = 10;
let delay = 3;
const run = setInterval(() => {
  console.log("Execute event....");
  time -= delay;
  if (time < delay) {
    console.log("Done");
    clearInterval(run);
  }
}, delay * 1000);
```

Comment: @PeterSeliger There are 2 hard problems in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-1 errors.